# Return Group by Values in MySql

Tags: mysql, group-by

Consider the following script to create the table structure and sample data

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (
FieldA VARCHAR(30),
FieldB VARCHAR(30),
FieldX varchar(50)
);
Insert into TableA (FieldA,FieldB,FieldX)
Values
('Big','Red','Apple'),
('Big','Red','Orangatang'),
('Small','Red','Cherry'),
('Small','Red','Ladybug')
```

If I run a Select with a Group by on say `FieldA`,`FieldB` like below

```
Select FieldA,FieldB from TableA group by FieldA,FieldB
```

is it possible to somehow extract all of the `FieldX` values from the records in each group? Ideally I want an output which has:

```
Big    | Red | 'Apple','Orangatang'
Small  | Red | 'Cherry','Ladybug'
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1487d/3)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the MySQL function [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to do this:

```
Select FieldA, FieldB, group_concat(fieldx) as concatenated_field
from TableA 
group by FieldA, FieldB
```

Comment: I kept getting values like 'Value,Value,' where the delimiter added at the end so did left((Group_Concat(Zip,'|')),CHAR_LENGTH(Group_Concat(Zip,'|'))-1) to solve it

Comment: @user3649739 I guess I misunderstood what you wanted the output to look like. Happy you managed to solve it :)

Answer (score 2):

[`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) should do the trick:

```
SELECT   fielda, fieldb, GROUP_CONCAT(fieldx)
from     tablea
GROUP BY fielda, fieldb
```

Comment: What an absolutely perfect function!